# How to synthesize programs with multiple types in Rosette?

Tags: racket, rosette

I am looking to write a DSL in Rosette with the goal of synthesizing a function.  The DSL is based off a very small subset of Haskell, and is strongly typed.  I therefore want to make sure that anything that Rosette generates is well-typed.

One way I could consider going about this is writing a "is-well-typed-code" function (that's something I've already done in Julia, which I'm porting from), and then assert that it must hold true of the synthesized function.  However, I do not see with `define-synthax` and `synthesize` how to view the code both as a syntactic object (i.e., an S-expr that can have any function applied to it) and as a semantic function when synthesizing.

I could also imagine using a `cond` inside the `define-synthax` module over all possible types of the arguments (this is a finite set for this small DSL), and defining the possible forms separately for each type.  However, including conds inside `define-synthax` does not seem to be possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `define-synthax`. Define structs for your AST explicitly, then you would have a syntactic object to operate on. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53714919/718349 on the issue of shallow vs deep embedding.